# plane with transparent image Texture does not get 100% transparent in shadows near object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, transparency, image

[image: Logo of Eichhof Beer Brand, on the wall of a white Beer stand. the transparent parts of the logo have a grey tint]I want to put a logo on a Beer stand. When Adding the image to the scene (using the "images as planes" import) everything looks good. When placing the plane on the stand, the plane that has the image as a texture is visible. The only difference is, that the plane is now in the shadow and not under direct sunlight. This also shows up in the final render and it happens as well when setting the alpha slider of the BSDF to 0 (meaning obviously no picture is visible but the plane still is).
Any Idea and help is appreciated!

**Settings:**
| Render engine: Cycles
| Max Samples: 100
| Total light bounces: 12
| Transparent light bounces: 10

**Specs:**
Apple M1 Max
Using Metal GPU
Blender 3.5.1

[image]

Comment: Can you share the failing section of your blend on https://blend-exchange.com/ (including your image, packed )?

Comment: What do you mean by "failing section" of my blend? The Image is strait from Wikipedia (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauerei_Eichhof)

Comment: Cheers! Some people include a lot of stuff in the file which has no bearing on their problem.. just avoiding that possibility. Will check the logo

Comment: I'm getting [no problem](https://imgur.com/a/RnfI1DA) with the logo, with absolutely default settings on my system, so there must be something else.. will need  your blend to check it out.

Comment: I opened a new project, imported the image and made a similar setup to my original file. The Issue didn't show up. Deleted everything and appended the collection of the file with the issue. the issue showed up. no idea what is happening here :)

Comment: How can i share my blend file with you? i'm new to this platform.

Comment: Hi. Marius.. see comment No.1,, no need to pack the image though..

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=3GnyMRSj" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/3GnyMRSj/)   Don't mind the name of the file :)

Comment: got it .. your plate is visible to Ambient Occlusion. 'Only  Local'  AO is a getaround, but IMO not the best. Will produce answer, this pm GMT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Ambient Occlusion for dirt-mapping, and a transparent plate for placing a logo on your surface.

It turns out to be a [known issue](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/95468) with the Ambient Occlusion shader that, for efficiency in an already relatively slow call, it does not take transparency into account, when it casts probing rays into the hemisphere around the shading-point, looking for hits.

You can eliminate the contribution of the plate to the beer stand's surface by setting the stand's AO node to 'Only Local'.

Personally, I think it would be better to UV map the beer-stand, lose the plate, and use the alpha of the image to mask it into the surface texture of the beer-stand itself, as  sketched in here:

[image]

Comment: Damn it, i overlooked that. Thank you very much for having a look at it! Thank you also for the detailed description of why the problem with ambient occlusion occurs. I know that UV unwrapping would be the correct way to do this but the project is extremely underpaid and the stand is only a "small" portion of a whole campus so i didn't bother to uv unwrap and texture in a detailed manner.

Comment: I got around the problem by using the knife tool an making an outline of the Logo, therefore getting rid of the transparent geometry. But i'm sure to check for AO the next time running into this problem! Have a great day/night and thanks again for your help.

Comment: np @Marius .. glad to be of help :)